# Gitlab CI Pipeline that runs after merge is done

Tags: merge, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to run specific script to move tags to main branch, after merge with develop branch is done with .gitlab-ci.yml.

The goal is to run job AFTER merge is done, I couldn't find appropriate way to do it. I tried to work with "merged results pipeline", but I don't know to to limit it to run only after merge is done.

Comment: Tags aren't in branches. You can delete a tag, then create a new tag of the same name pointing to a different commit (or combine these two steps with `git tag -f`), but ... don't do that, people don't expect that and it messes other people up.

Comment: thing is, that after merge is done, I need to move tags to latest commit on main branch. at this moment we do this manually after merging, I want to automate this process

Comment: Again: what do you mean by "move" the tags? (Tags contain a hash ID, and you are not supposed to change the stored hash ID.)

Comment: sorry, I have used the language that was clear for my colleagues as this process is performed. After an merge on main branch is done I need to change all tags to point on the newest (merge) commit. I have managed to do so, I enclose the pipeline that worked for me.

Comment: OK - it appears this is a question about a specific set of GitLab pipeline operators, not about Git. And "move a tag" winds up meaning "force-reset a tag in the way that Git recommends never doing" (there are some specific limited situations where it's OK, but they're not very common).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below I paste the code that worked for me.

```
move_tags:
  stage: move_tags
  allow_failure: true
  timeout: 24h
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"'
      when: manual
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer will run the pipeline on commit if `when: manual` is not present to avoid this you can use Gitlab ci predefined variable $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED this will return true after merge and available from gitlab v14.1.

If you want to run the pipeline when merge request is created to main branch you can use $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME with $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED.

you can add the rule like this in your job.

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "main"
```